# GCP load balancing ("internal" traffic over HTTPS)

Tags: apache, load-balancing, google-vpc

I have a GCP instance group with 2 instances. Both are up and running. I want to configure a load balancer (HTTPS) to manage the traffic.

I've set up a forwarding rule with the HTTP-protocol and a certificate managed by google. This all works, but only when the traffic **between the load balancer and the backend** (the instances) is plain HTTP.

**Steps I did so far**

- I create a template and this template is just a normal N1 series machine. I checked the boxes to create firewall rules for allowing http and https traffic.
- I create a firewall rule named "allow-ports". This firewall rule targets all instances in the network, has a 0.0.0.0/0 IP-range and allow port tcp = 80, 443. How I see this, this firewall rule should open both the http (80) and https (443) port.
- I create an instance group with port mapping. "http-port" = 80, "https-port" = 443. I use the template I just created.
- When the instance group is created, I check if this is running. With SSH, I get access to the instances and install apache (sudo apt-get install -y apache2) on the both. When navigating to their external IP's in the browser, I see them both.
- I create a HTTP(S) load balancer, with the option "From internet to my VMs". For backend configuration, I add a backend service with my instance group, protocol HTTP, named port "http-port". For frontend configuration, I set up the HTTPS protocol, create an IPv4 IP address, create a google-managed ssl certificate, and I'm done. I also added health checks btw.

Now... these steps work (after a few minutes). With the cloud DNS, I have set up a domain name which points to the IP address of the load balancer. When going to , I see the apache page.

**What doesn't work?**

When I change the backend configuration to HTTPS (and named port "https-port"), I get a 502 server error. So it seems to me that there is some connection, but there is an error. Could this be an apache error?

I have spent a whole day, creating and recreating instance groups, firewall rules, load balancers, ... but nothing seems to work. I'm surely missing something, probably something dumb, but I have no clue what it could be.

**What do I want to achieve?**

I do not only want a secure (HTTPS) connection between the client and my load balancer, I also want a secure connection between the load balancer and the backend service (the instance group). Because GCP offers the option to use the HTTPS protocol when creating a backend service, I feel that this could be done.

To be honest: I'm reading some articles about the fact that the internal traffic is secured, so a HTTPS connection is not necessary. But that doesn't matter to me, I really want to know how this works!

**EDIT**

I'm using the correct VPC (default). I also edited the firewall rule from 0.0.0.0/0 to 130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16 (see: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/globally-autoscaling-a-web-service-on-compute-engine?hl=nl#configure_the_load_balancer).

Comment: Have you setup HTTPS on the backends? If not, then you cannot use HTTPS between the load balancer and the backends.

Comment: Let me run a simple experiment - I will get back to you with the results :)

Comment: @Wojciech Bogacz thank you, that's very kind!

Comment: @John Hanley: do you mean I have to setup a SSL certificate on the apache servers on the instances?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use HTTPS to the backends,

Comment: SSL certs are necessary also on back-end if you want HTTPS, and you can even use self-signed ones or expired - it will still work. I want to do this experiment though to give you a list of steps how to set it up in GCE.

Comment: A 502 error is a "bad gateway" response. Have you changed the health check from  default HTTP to HTTPS when you switched your backend to HTTPS? Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#optional-flags-hc-protocol-http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my previous comment. I followed your steps at my test project to find out the cause of your issue. I installed the same configuration and checked it with HTTP at the back-end. As it was expected, I found no errors. After that, I installed SSL certificates to the back-end and to the load balancer. Then I switched my back-end, load balancer and health checks to HTTPS and disabled HTTP at the back-end. At this point, I found no errors also.

So, I decided to get 502 error in my test configuration in some way. I switched my health check at the load balancer to HTTP. A few minutes later I tried to reach my test service again and got 502 error. When I switched back my health check to HTTPS 502 error gone away.

During this test, I didn't change firewall rules, but allowed HTTP and HTTPS traffic in my instance template and I used default network.

Comment: I didn't install HTTPS to my backend, I guess that was the problem. Thank you for your answer, I think I can reproduce it now.